# Duda con operador '=' varias veces en una sentencia

Tags: java

Quisiera saber porqué este código imprime `3,1` y no otro valor:

```
Point a,b,c;

b = new Point(2,4);
a = new Point(3,1);
c = b = a;
c = new Point(1,2);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: te ha servido la respuesta?

Comment: Más allá del [link de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta. Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Muchas gracias, completamente entendido (:

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te ha servido, deberías marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 6):

El operador de asignación (`=`) se aplica de derecha a izquierda. Es decir, sobre el operando a izquierda se realiza la operación tomando el operando a derecha.

En el caso concreto de `c = b = a;` la variable `a` no se ve modificada por la asignación. Las variables `c` y `b` en este caso se les asigna el objeto referenciado por `a`.

La sentencia se evalua como `c = (b = a)` como ha señalado @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos.

Ahora bien, tus variables (`a b c`) son referencias a objetos `Point`. No son el objeto en sí.

Cuando haces `c= New Point(1,2)` creas un nuevo objeto `Point` y este nuevo objeto es referenciado por `c`. No estás accediendo al objeto al que referenciado `c`. No es la semántica del `=` en el lenguaje para este caso.

Es por ello que cuando imprimes en pantalla `a` ves `(3,1)`.

Referencias:

[Wikilibros - Programación en Java](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Operadores_de_asignaci%C3%B3n)

[SO-en - Initializing multiple variables to the same value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202818/initializing-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-java)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Yo añadiría que `a = b = c` se evalúa como `a = ( b = c )`

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos tomo tu comentario y agrego.

Comment: @ElAsiduo de acuerdo con la igualdad, pero si `Point` es mutable, porque no imprime `1,2`?